# View structure of file in Atom

Tags: github, atom-editor

I am used to IDEs like Eclipse and Intellij and am trying to completely switch over to Atom. Few of the things I have been unable to figure out (or found packages for):
1. How to view the structure of the file in Atom. For e.g. a shortcut that would show me the classes/methods/variables in a file so that I can jump from one to the other quickly.
2. How to go to the declaration of a method or class? I see "Go to declaration" as one of the options when I right click but it does not seem to do anything -- at least for php files. Am I missing something there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For `1.) How to view the structure of the file in Atom. For e.g. a shortcut that would show me the classes/methods/variables in a file so that I can jump from one to the other quickly` you could use [symbols-tree-view](https://atom.io/packages/symbols-tree-view) which I just discovered because I was searching for the same functionality. You can browse for classes, functions, vars, ... and click on them to get there.

Your question `2.) How to go to the declaration of a method or class? I see "Go to declaration" as one of the options when I right click but it does not seem to do anything -- at least for php files. Am I missing something there?` should be answered, too by this, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/alibaba/structure-view

> Structure View for ATOM editor, just like Outline view in Eclipse or Structure tool window in IDEA / WebStorm, provides quick navigation for symbols of source code with a tree view.